# Definable Sets of ($\mathbb{Z};<$)

Tags: model-theory

I came across this question "Prove that a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is definable in the structure $(\mathbb{Z};<)$ if and only if $S=\emptyset $ or $S=\mathbb{Z}$."

I found something on the wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set), but I would like some elaboration. I'm not sure what parameters mean here in the article, which is probably why I don't understand the explanation.

My own attempt to understand goes something like that: if $S$ is definable, then there exists a formula such that the truth is preserved by elements of $S$. Since any two integers are "connected" by the translation function, if $a$ belongs to $S$, then $a+k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is also in $S$, hence $S=\mathbb{Z}$. Also, the formula $\exists v_1<(v_1,v_1)$ defines the empty set.

Am I right? How do I prove the converse?

Comment: Your formula defines the empty set, though $x\lt x$ would be clearer. One can come up with a similar definiton of the full set.

Comment: I find it strange that the question and the answers were downvoted.

Comment: @Asaf: Same feeling

Comment: Thank you @AndréNicolas. Does the negation of $x<x$ define the full set then?

Comment: Yes, that will do it. If your formalization is (as is likely the case) in the predicate calculus with equality, one can use $x=x$.

Comment: okay. thank you for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your various questions:

1. Parameters mean additional free variables which are fixed when considering this. For example $\{k\in\Bbb Z\mid k<0\}$ is definable using the parameter $0$.

   But usually definable means definable without parameters (although in some contexts, like set theory, definable might mean definable with parameters).
2. Your solution is right. If $a\in S$, then the translation by $k$ preserves truth values, so $a+k\in S$. Therefore either $S=\Bbb Z$ or $S=\varnothing$.

   More generally we consider functions which are bijections of the structure's universe with itself and preserve the interpretation of the symbols in the language (in this case, $f(x)<f(y)\iff x<y$). These are called *automorphisms*, and we can show that if $A$ is a definable set, then for any automorphism, $f(A)=A$. Precisely because these preserve truth values.

   Your argument was essentially this. Whether or not you have verified that $f_k(a)=a+k$ is indeed an automorphism is a different question, but it's not hard to show that it is indeed a bijection of $\Bbb Z$ with itself, and preserves the order.
3. The other direction? You mean showing that there is a formula which defines $\Bbb Z$ (you already gave one defining $\varnothing$). I'm sure that you can think about a formula that is satisfied by all the members of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: thank you so much! you cleared my doubts perfectly. Just one more question: to prove the if and only if, is it necessary for the construction of the formula that is satisfied by all the members of $\mathbb{Z}$? Will it be sufficient to use the automorphism?

Comment: To show that a set is definable you need to exhibit a formula that defines it. It has nothing to do with automorphisms. Automorphisms are used to show that something is not definable.

Comment: I see. I will go think about the other formula then. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that if a set is definable in a structure then it is fixed (set-wise) under automorphisms. Since $x \to x+1$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{Z},<)$ fixes no subsets except $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, you have your result.

Comment: I don't quite understand this. What does it mean to be fixed set-wise?

Comment: $F(A)=A$ but it might not be true that $F(a)=a$, $\forall a \in A$.

Comment: @jh4: The method (in practice) to show a set is not definable is to exhibit an automorphism which does not define the set. I'll link you to a proof of this fact

Comment: @jh4: Actually, this fact is mentioned at the bottom of the wikipedia page.

Comment: yes I did read that in the wiki page. Thank you for elaborating. I have some problems understanding the wiki page, but the answers here have helped alot.

Comment: You meant to write the converse: *If* a set is definable in a structure, *then* it is fixed by automorphisms! (Don't worry, I did not downvote)

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Oops! Thanks for the catch. Changed "if" to "then"

Comment: @KyleGannon Logic is hard :)